# Resizing Image inside a heading tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to resize an image to make it responsive, which is placed inside a `<h1>` tag. 
My code:

```
<div id="header" class="clearfix">
    <h1 id="logo" >
        <img alt="" src="/images/layouts/logo.png"/>
    </h1>
    <div id="heading">
        <h2>Sample<span class="white">Title</span></h2>
        <p class="white">Some Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }

.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

and for the `<h1>` tag

```
h1 { font-size: 2em; margin-top: 0.75em; margin-bottom: 0.75em; }
```

I've tried resizing the font size in h1

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
#header #logo h1 {

        font-size: 5px;
        margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px;
    }}
```

But there seems to be no effect. What should I do to decrease the size of `<h1>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the h1 tag that you need to resize. If you inspect your element, you will find your h1 resizes fine, but your image is blocking the width. You want to make the image, at most, no larger that the page width.

Put `max-width: 100%;` on your `img`:

```css
#header #logo img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```